# Best way to load jqGrid with static data?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

We load 10 rows of static data into our jqGrid by creating a JSON string:

```
var d = "{\"page\":1,\"records\":10,\"total\":1,\"rows\":[" +
                "{\"id\":\"1\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"2\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"3\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"4\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"5\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"6\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"7\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"8\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"9\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}," +
                "{\"id\":\"10\",\"cell\":[\"\"]}" +
            "]}";
```

And loading that into a grid with `datatype:jsonstring` and `datastr:d` where our grid has 15 columns and each column is created using a custom formatter.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correspond to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) (see description of the `data` parameter)

> It can replace addRowData method which
>   is slow on relative big data

I don't made any measure myself, but the usage of `data` parameter seems me also as one of the most effective ways. It is important **how many rows of data** you want to add. The parameter `datastr` used together with `datatype:jsonstring` is relatively old way existing before introducing in the version 3.7 the local paging of data. With respect of the `data` parameter you can add **large** set of pure data, sort it and display the first page of the data. The filling of the first page with the data from the `data` parameter will be done with respect of `addJSONData` function so the part of work is the same in all cases. Only the filling of data which size is grater as the page size makes the way with the `data` parameter more effective.

If you will use `data` parameter you should don't forget to define additional `id` property in the data array. It can be either the property with default `id` name or another name defined in `localReader`. If you defined `key:true` for one column of the jqGrid, then including of additional `id` property is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: **yes**

How? Render a regular table, then use Jqgrid's plugin called "grid.tbltogrid.js". Very useful and simple. Internally it uses "addRowData" method of the jqgrid, but why you need to repeat the written code, right? ;)