# How to define a way that JQGrid manage row IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, client-side, data-visualization

What I want to achieve is by event on cell I want to load TimeSeries data associated with value in cell and plot it in graph on page. I use JQGrid and Flot.

In its [Docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) I see event `onCellSelect`. It has two parameters - `iCol` and `rowid`. 
And what is hinders me is uncertainty about how JQGrid assign this IDs to columns and rows, and so how can I, when this event fired, associate this `rowid` and `iCol` with right columns and rows from timeseries.

Will appreciate any thoughts on that.

Comment: Will you not be passing into the grid your own ID information for the data you are displaying?

Comment: I dont have preferences in that - my setup allows me to index TimeSeries data as I want and pass it to table (I just dont know how to do that with JQGrid). Or I can somehow adjust my setup to match the way  how JQGrid assign this IDs (if its in order of initial JSON data - it would be easy). I will follow best possible solution.

Comment: Then I would suggest you just add an ID column to the grid (it doesn't have to be shown) and you use that as depending on the sort order, etc the rowId is going to be different.

Comment: Would that work for your problem/use case in your project?

Comment: Of course! How that ID from hidden column can be passed in `onCellSelect` event?

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in an ID value and place it in a hidden column. You can access that value from the select event as shown below:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
        var hiddenIdValue = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'HiddenIdColumn')
        ....
```

Comment: Well heh, as part of your jqGrid setup in your client side setup you can specify the function to preform when the onSelectRow event happens. In the example above I show you how to extract your value and assign it to a variable.  If you search for jqGrid examples you will see where you can plug this in.  the `...` are where you would add your code to do whatever it is you were going to do on the client.

Comment: Why you use customize onSelectRow, and not onCellSelect?

Comment: No technical reason, I assumed you would have a user selecting rows not individual cells.

Comment: By the way - if I use `key:True` for `HiddenIdColumn` - will it passed to event as `rowid` by JQGrid?

Comment: Checking the documentation `In case if there is no id from server, this can be set as as id for the unique row id. Only one column can have this property. If there are more than one key the grid finds the first one and the second is ignored.` So looks like you would be right.

Comment: Also take a look at this answer ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4408870/1818608)). Seems its author one of jqgrid devs.

Comment: Oleg is a frequent contributor to the project but I don't believe an author.  He is definitely the go to source of information and very informative so his posts are always a wealth of information.  in short he is a beast.

Comment: Im noticed ([link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)) that event handlers can be defined with number of arguments that differs from signature of parameters in Dodcs. For example in top part of page that I linked `onSelectRow` defined as just `function(id)`, what is it? Is this JS feature?

Comment: Indeed JS will not care if you do not include a partial list of function parameters or even overload them.